# Ubuntu 16.04 dropping IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses

Tags: linux-kernel, ipv6

I have a Debian 11(kernel version 5.10.0-6) and Ubuntu 16.04(kernel version 4.4.0-201) in the same broadcast domain. Both systems have an [iputils traceroute6 version s20121221](http://www.skbuff.net/iputils/iputils-s20121221.tar.bz2) installed and firewall allows all the IPv6 traffic. Now the problem is, that Ubuntu installation does not pass the [IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses) to `traceroute6` utility. I can see that the packets reach the system, but `traceroute6` does not see those. When I execute the `strace -f ./traceroute6 -d -q1 -n fc00::10:2:34:30` command in the Debian 11 system, then the output related to fourth hop(`::ffff:172.16.0.2`) can be seen below:

```
setsockopt(4, SOL_IPV6, IPV6_UNICAST_HOPS, [4], 4) = 0
sendto(4, "\0\0'\335\0\0\0\4Y\266\263`\0\0\0\0K\267\6\0\0\0\0\0", 24, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(33434), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "fc00::10:2:34:30", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 24
select(4, [3], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=5, tv_usec=0}) = 1 (in [3], left {tv_sec=4, tv_usec=988513})                                                                                                                                                                                                
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(0), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:172.16.0.2", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, msg_namelen=28, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\3\0R4\t\0\0\0`\v\207\265\0 \21\2\374\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\1\0\22\0\21"..., iov_len=512}], ms
g_iovlen=1, msg_control=[{cmsg_len=36, cmsg_level=SOL_IPV6, cmsg_type=0x32}, {cmsg_len=36, cmsg_level=SOL_IPV6, cmsg_type=0x2}], msg_controllen=80, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 152                                                                                                                     write(1, " 4  ::ffff:172.16.0.2  12.777 ms", 32 4  ::ffff:172.16.0.2  12.777 ms) = 32                                                                                                                                                                                                          
write(1, "\n", 1                                                                                                                               
)                       = 1
```

As seen above, after sending the packet to `fc00::10:2:34:30` in the `sendto()`, the `recvmsg()` receives the packet from `::ffff:172.16.0.2`. However, in case of Ubuntu 16.04 system, the `recvmsg()` never receives the packet:

```
setsockopt(4, SOL_IPV6, IPV6_UNICAST_HOPS, [4], 4) = 0
sendto(4, "\0\0Q\222\0\0\0\4\346\267\263`\0\0\0\0\365\241\1\0\0\0\0\0", 24, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(33434), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "fc00::10:2:34:30", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 24
select(4, [3], NULL, NULL, {5, 0})      = 0 (Timeout)
write(1, " 4  *", 5 4  *)                    = 5
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
```

As seen above, the fourth hop is a `*` in the Ubuntu 16.04 system. Socket definition in `iputils` `traceroute6` is following:

`socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP)`

The problem is specifically with IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses. Other types of IPv6 packets are processed fine in the Ubuntu system.

What might cause such behavior?

Comment: I don't see how a IPv4-mapped IPv6 address even comes into play here. These addresses (of the form `::ffff:192.168.0.1`) are IPv6 representations of real IPv4 addresses. You are not using IPv4 to send your messages, the destination address is an IPv6 address.

Comment: @JohanMyréen The router on the fourth hop does not have IPv6 addresses configured and it picks its IPv4 address on the loopback interface as a source address for the ICMPv6 "time exceeded" messages. For example, Cisco routers running IOS-XR behave like that. Packet itself is not routed using the IPv6 addresses, but switched using MPLS labels.

Comment: @Martin OK, this clears up things. However, I stand by my claim that the packet you should be receiving from the router is a normal IPv4 packet, not an IPv6 packet. The `::ffff:172.16.0.2` is just an IPv6 representation of an IPv4 address that is used when an IPv4 packet is received on a IPv6 socket. No packets with addresses `::ffff:n.n.n.n` are transmitted on the wire. Now, the reason why the traceroute6 program doesn't see the packet could be that it has set the IPV6_V6ONLY option on the socket, either explicitly or it has been set globally using `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only`.

Comment: @JohanMyréen At least when using the MPLS "tunneling", the packets with addresses `::ffff:n.n.n.n` are transmitted on wire. If the fourth hop router receives an UDP datagram addressed to `fc00::10:2:34` with an hop-limit 1, then it has to reply with ICMPv6 "time exceeded" message and not with the ICMP "time exceeded" message and some kind of IPv6 address has to be used as a source address. `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only` is `0` both in the `Debian` and `Ubuntu` server.

Comment: Well, if the router really sends packets with such source addresses then I guess Cisco never got the memo "IPv4-Mapped Addresses on the Wire Considered Harmful". I find it strange that your network includes a router that is supposed to handle IPv6, but has no IPv6 addresses configured.

Comment: @JohanMyréen The router could not possibly send back an IPv4 packet [as you suggest](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/187960/johan-myr%c3%a9en).  The router has received an ICMPv6 packet from an IPv6 address. The TTL expired so it dutifully sends back a [Time Exceeded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Time_exceeded) ICMPv6 packet to the **IPv6** source address of the original.  It cannot possibly do that over IPv4.

Comment: @JohanMyréen Secondly, IPv6 only requires routers to have a link-local IPv6 address.  The only practical reason for a GUA or ULA on a router is to allow access to the management UI.  So a router with no Global Unicast Address is perfectly acceptable and quite common.  Leaving the question of what a router *should* write in the source address of an ICMPv6 Time Exceeded packet.  It's only there for information, not routing...  The choice is between a link local address or an IPv4 mapped address. The link-local address is meaningless for routing and potentially duplicate with other devices.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Well, I guess you have convinced me the packet is an ICMPv6 packet. I still find it strange that an IPv4 mapped address is used as the source address. As you say, a link-local address is meaningless for routing, so isn't the router meaningless as an IPv6 router if it only has link-local addresses configured? What does the router choose as the source address if it didn't have an IPv4 address configured?

Comment: @JohanMyréen No, it's still a router.  Other machines on the same link can send packets to it's link-local address and it will forward using routing tables as per normal. The point bing, it can be attached to a physical subnet containing many machines on the same logical IPv6 subnet. It never needs it's own IP on that subnet because [Neighbor Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol) lets it advertise it's link-local address to everything on the physical subnet.  Then everything on the subnet can talk through it using it's link-local address.